# Displaying Single Name Entry with Total Count From Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have uploaded a bunch of entries from a CSV file and need to display the number of entries by company. I am able to get the information to display in a JSON object in the HTML, but it displays for each entry in the database rather than displaying once for each company. I need it to look like this:

```
ABC Dirtworks 4
Dirt Diggler 2
John Doe Mining 2
Spider Crawlers 2
Standard Tractor and Machines 3
```

What currently shows looks more like this:

```
ABC DirtWorks   {"ABC DirtWorks"=>4, "Dirt Diggler"=>2, "John Doe Mining"=>2, "Spider Crawlers"=>2, "Standard Tractor and Machines"=>3}
John Doe Mining {"ABC DirtWorks"=>4, "Dirt Diggler"=>2, "John Doe Mining"=>2, "Spider Crawlers"=>2, "Standard Tractor and Machines"=>3}
ABC DirtWorks   {"ABC DirtWorks"=>4, "Dirt Diggler"=>2, "John Doe Mining"=>2, "Spider Crawlers"=>2, "Standard Tractor and Machines"=>3}
ABC DirtWorks   {"ABC DirtWorks"=>4, "Dirt Diggler"=>2, "John Doe Mining"=>2, "Spider Crawlers"=>2, "Standard Tractor and Machines"=>3}
John Doe Mining {"ABC DirtWorks"=>4, "Dirt Diggler"=>2, "John Doe Mining"=>2, "Spider Crawlers"=>2, "Standard Tractor and Machines"=>3}
```

Etc., Etc., Etc.

This is my model:

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  require 'csv'

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers:true) do |row|
      Vehicle.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end

  def count
    Vehicle.group(:company_name).count
  end
end
```

This is my controller:

```
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @vehicles = Vehicle.all
  end

  def import
    Vehicle.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to '/', notice: 'Your files were successfully uploaded!'
  end
end
```

And this is my view, as it pertains to this section:

```
  <tbody>
    <% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= vehicle.company_name %></td>
      <td><%= vehicle.count %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this code here:

```
def count
  Vehicle.group(:company_name).count
end
```

This is saying "count all the vehicles grouped by company name" but you are using it here:

```
  <td><%= vehicle.count %></td>
```

and what you seem to want here is "for this instance of a vehicle, count how many vehicles there are"

ie the code is not behaving the way you want because they are doing two different things.

So... what you want to do is not call count on every *instance* of a vehicle (and you probably want to rename the count method to something that is more descriptive and not as easily mistaken for a "normal" count) eg try something like:

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  def self.company_counts
    Vehicle.group(:company_name).count
  end
end

class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @vehicles = Vehicle.all
    @counts = Vehicle.company_counts
  end
end

<% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= vehicle.company_name %></td>
    <td><%= @counts[vehicle.company_name] %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! And thank you for the code clean-up. ;) I'm new to all of this. So, that worked to pull the correct data from the JSON object, now I just need to figure out how to display a single instance of the company name.

Comment: Do you have a uniqueness validation on your company name? it's possible you just have duplicate records in your db... the code looks correct for only showing one of each.

Answer (score 0):

Taryn answer is correct, but I would go with one query:

```
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @counts_by_company = Vehicle.company_counts
  end
end

<% @counts_by_company.each do |company, count| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= company %></td>
    <td><%= count %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The "@vehicle" is necessary for a separate part of the HTML that wasn't displayed in this question, where the vehicle information is displayed once the CSV has been uploaded.